# Failed to return information from external database with Objective-C and JSON

Tags: php, objective-c, json

I have a little problem. I am trying to retrieve information from an external database using php and Json.
If I try from localhost, it works, but if I modify the URL and put the external URL, it returns nothing.
In short, if I work locally (xampp and phpmyadmin) works, I returned the populations from the database, but if I try to do it from an external DB does not work.
There is something wrong with the code?
If I run the php scrip hosted on the external server, it returns the data. It is problem of Objective-C code

```
//Método que devuelve las poblaciones

-(NSMutableArray * )obtenerPoblaciones
{
pobla = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  

URLpobalciones = @"http://deproba.netau.net/devolver_poblaciones.php";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLpobalciones];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;
NSArray *items = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions     error:&error];


NSDictionary *item = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
// This will print all the names of people in your JSON.
for (item in items)
{
    NSString *poblae =[NSString stringWithFormat:[item valueForKey:@"nombre"]];
    [pobla addObject:poblae];
}

return pobla;
```

}

---

### MODIFICATION

Hello again! I modified the code. I want to get something simple and then complicate it more.
I modified the php script and objective-c code

### PHP File

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$miArray = array(utf8_encode("París")=>"Francia", "Madrid"=>utf8_encode("España"));
echo(json_encode($miArray));
?>
```

### OBJECTIVE-C CODE

```
//NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=g8production"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://prueba.vacau.com/php/prueba.php"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

if (jsonData != nil) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:    (NSJSONReadingMutableContainers) error:&error];
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Poblacion %@",result);
    }else
    {
        NSLog(@"jsonData  is empty");
    }
}
```

If I use the URL (http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=g8production), it works fine, but if I use my php script does not work. Make the if / else statement printing: jsonData is empty
I hope you can help me. Thanks again!

Comment: Disable your firewall and check again.

Comment: I run your code thru debugger. It gets the data but the deserialization fails. Do one thing: remove all unicode chars from the json string and try again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is on the server side. Probably unicode related. If you don't have access to the server, you will not be able to find out.

Comment: Now, I have done this:
If (data == nil)
NSLog(@"Data NOT have data");
else
{
NSLog(@"Data have data");
}
and the debugger print this --> Data have data.
This means that NSDATA recieves data from the URL, but not print out.
Tomorrow, I will try connect to the server. I will ask the credentials and we  talk again. Here, in Spain now is too later. Thanks for all, tomorrow more! :)

Comment: Hi again Adam! Finally, I have created a new free hosting to testing. I have copied the php files, and I've created a new database. All work in a browser, but not in a xcode console, what can I prove now that I have access to the files?

Comment: Of course! http://farmaribera.vacau.com/php/devolver_poblaciones.php

Comment: The result is exactly the same as the previous one. I'm afraid i can't help you with php :-(

Comment: You think that the problem is in php? Thanks for all Adam! Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I can't write a comment, so it must be an answer. I agree. Your code seems to be alright, the problem must have to do something with your server script.

But regarding what I see:

```
pobla = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

This must be an iVar as I see. Use accessors instead. Don't directly use the iVar's name. If you don't have ARC enabled in your project, you are probably leaking memory. Use autorelease instead after having set it via a retain property.

Then I don't understand why you use this:

```
NSDictionary *item = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
// This will print all the names of people in your JSON.
for (item in items) {...}
```

If you are thinking of fast enumeration, you could write:

```
for (NSDictionary *item in items) {...}
```

You don't need to explicitly alloc the objects your are enumerating. They are already there within items array.

Comment: I am using ARC in the project. The code you see, I found it online. I found another website where you explain how to use JSON IOS5.
I will modify the above code, I'm going to structure better and perhaps more easy to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

It works! I found the error, trying to validate the JSON on jsonlint.com The problem is the free hosting. Add advertising and JSON validator tells you that the JSON format is not correct. I tested on a real-hosting, and it works. The console displays the value you get JSON from PHP Thanks for all! You are cool